# How to make a square photo?

Tags: overleaf

I use altacv.cls and there is some pattern that allows to make only round photo (i use "\photoL" tag) , but i need square. I have no idea how to edit class to do this. I left the link of CV template below.
https://ru.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-nicolasomar-fork/htfpmrwhbwpw

Comment: I don't have an overleaf account and am not going to open one, but the part of the template you can see without logging in says, "Use the 'normalphoto' option if you want a normal photo"; have you tried changing the \documentclass` line to include the "normalphoto" option (in the square brackets, comma separatated, before `{altacv}`)?

Comment: Yea, u are right. Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper,normalphoto]{altacv}`

[image]

Comment: Yeap, thank u very much. It's wokrs.